# I can't change background color of dynamically created element more than 2 times

Tags: javascript, background-color

Im trying to make to do list. It should be like this, if i click on a task element it must change back color to blue and if i click it second time it should change it back to the same color. My problem is that i can't change it to blue and back more than 2 times. Here is my code.

```
function getValue() {
let result = document.createElement('h4')
let att = document.createAttribute('class')

att.value = 'pId'
result.innerHTML = input.value

document.body.appendChild(result);
result.setAttributeNode(att)

// change color

let colorArr = ['blue', 'rgb(184, 58, 58)']
let i = 0

result.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result.style.backgroundColor = colorArr[i]
  i = i+1
}
)
```

}

Comment: Please can you add a snippet of your HTML so as it is possible to actually test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the remainder operator to reset the index back to the first index; otherwise, it will keep incrementing the index past the length of the array.

```
result.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result.style.backgroundColor = colorArr[i];
  i = (i + 1) % colorArr.length;//works for any number of colors
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in the click event listener, just apply a new class to the element using `element.classList.toggle("myclass");`.
This will add or remove the class from the element depending of it having the class.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the color changes only twice is because once `i` becomes greater than the number of items in the list, there will be no more colors to assign `i` to.
So in order to achieve the desired result, use this instead

```
result.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result.style.backgroundColor = colorArr[i]
  i = i+1
  if (i >= colorArr.length) {i = 0}
}
```

Hope its not confusing